# iptables mac address filtering

Tags: iptables, vps

How do I grant access to a server based on mac address?  (This is a VPS)

According to google searches, this is the syntax to allow a certain mac address...

iptables -A INPUT  -m mac --mac-source  c4:2c:03:30:14:1f  -j ACCEPT

I get useless error messages along the lines of "iptables: Unknown error 18446744073709551615".  (Tried it on ubuntu and centos)
Is my syntax wrong?  Or is the concept fundamentally flawed.  Like, is it impossible to filter mac addresses on a VPS.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept is probably flawed, depending on how you're trying to use it.

The MAC address is what's used for communication on the same broadcast domain - so, in cases when one node is talking to another on the same subnet, the source MAC of the packet will actually be the MAC of the source node.  However, when traffic is routed, the source MAC changes as it passes through each network segment.

In practical terms:  If you're trying to allow all traffic from another VPS on the same broadcast domain, then this should work (it seems like your `iptables` is having issues with the MAC module).  Otherwise, if the source system is outside the subnet (say, a device you're using to manage the VPS), then this is not a workable approach; the source MAC on all traffic routed from the internet is going to be the VPS's first-hop router.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  While I still don't know why I get an error, at least now I know not to waste time with it anymore.  I was trying to match a _remote_ mac address, so it wouldn't have done what I wanted anyway.  Thanks.